# Polygon coords are backwards

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have been given a delimited text file with a series of polygons representing areas in the UK. I have a column labelled WKT_LatLong and the column contains the polygons. When I import the data it shows the polygons off the east coast of Africa and not in Torquay where I would expect it to be. The co-ordinates are backwards it seems, they are lat/long and QGIS seems to be reading them in as long/lat. I'm a QGIS n00b and can't find any documentation to fix this. Everything I read about WKT seems to show the co-ordinates as long/lat.

How can I convert this polygon:

```
POLYGON ((50.96831893 -1.72537935, 50.96840716 -1.72553119, 50.96826674 -1.72657135, 50.96757606 -1.72772179, .........)) //QGIS places this off the West coast of Africa
```

to:

```
POLYGON ((-1.72537935 50.96831893, -1.72553119 50.96840716..................)) //QGIS puts this where I would expect it.
```

There is a new polygon or multipolygon on each line and they're all different sizes.

I took one line and manually changed it with some Excel bodging but that's not going to work long term for all of the files.

Before I invest time wrangling with Python, I'm hoping someone will point me at a checkbox or util that does this for me.

Comment: 50 degrees is the east coast of Africa, not the west. You are probably loading the file using the wrong projection so it reads degrees as if they were meters, so within 180 meters around 0;0 which is indeed near the west coast.

Comment: Sorry I had meant east coast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the reversed layer as a delimited text layer, calculate a new wkt column with `geom_to_wkt( flip_coordinates( $geometry))`, export to a new csv file and import it back using the calculated wkt column for the geometry.

[image]